# How to change paper size to "A5" in printform component in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, printform

I need to change paper size to A5 in Printform but I can't set true properties.

```
pf.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.PaperName()
```

In this line I don't know how should I write for `paperName`

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution.

```
printform.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.RawKind = Printing.PaperKind.A5
```